# magicSuggest is not updating/refreshing data: on ajax success

Tags: magicsuggest

Below is the code i'm using to populate data for magicSuggest box. For the first time it is getting correct values in dropdown but on change of dependent dropdown its not changing its data.

```
        $(document).on("change",".specilitydrop", function() {
            var select = $(this);
            var newVal = select.val();
            //alert(newVal);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url : "<?php echo LIVE_SITE; ?>/users/findSubSplProfile/"+newVal,
                success: function (data)
                {   $('#subSpecialityData').magicSuggest({ 
                        width: 495,
                        sortOrder: 'value',
                        selectionPosition: 'bottom',
                        selectionStacked: true,
                        displayField: 'value',
                        data: $.parseJSON(data)
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Calling $('#subSpecialityData').magicSuggest multiple times won't create multiple components. Rather it will keep the same component. If you want to set new data every time, you should delete the component and its associated DOM prior to recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass data by using magicSuggest's option, instead of ajax callback

```
$('#subSpecialityData').magicSuggest({ 
     width: 495,
     sortOrder: 'value',
     selectionPosition: 'bottom',
     selectionStacked: true,
     displayField: 'value',
     method: "post",
     data: "users/findSubSplProfile/"+newVal
});
```